# Uploading MP4 video from iOS gives me a MOV

Tags: ios, html, video, mp4

I have some MP4 videos on an iPad which I'm trying to upload to our HTML5 web app. The app only accepts MP4 (video/streaming is not the app's primary function).

Problem is, when I go to upload the video the server is receiving a .mov (MIME: video/quicktime). From what I can tell the brief "Compressing Now..." dialog in iOS must convert the file - this happens in Safari and Chrome alike.

I thought I could get around this by adding an 'accept' property to the file upload:

```
<input onchange='startupload();' type='file' accept='video/mp4' id='uploadme'>
```

... but while that changes the UI behaviour slightly (image icon becomes a video), it still lands me with a .mov

Is there something I'm missing here - can I get an MP4 uploaded or is this no longer possible? For the sake of this simple upload I really don't want to go down the road of server-side conversion in FFMPEG etc.

Comment: Get a free tool called `MediaInfo` and drag one of those files into the window. It should tell you the true codec & container formats of your file. Either you have actual quicktime MOV file secretly renamed as MP4. Or else your HTML5 app is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MOV and MP4 files have almost the same structure!

Apple developed MOV format, and later standardized it as MP4 in MPEG committee. AFAIK MP4 supports more audio codecs, but in 99% cases these 2 formats are the same.